# Pandas treating a float column as non-numeric?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does Pandas print different types of output for `describe()` on two columns that are both of type `float64`?

My codes is:

```
print '\nBRANDED\n'
print df['branded'].describe()
print '\nGENERIC\n'
print df['generic'].describe()
```

This outputs:

```
BRANDED

count     5158
unique     182
top          1
freq       334
Name: branded, dtype: float64

GENERIC

count     7955.000000
mean      5465.802137
std       4028.148729
min          1.000000
25%       2617.000000
50%       4523.000000
75%       7264.000000
max      42788.000000
Name: generic, dtype: float64
```

If both columns are of type `float64`, then why does the first column not look like it is numeric?

It probably has some nulls in it, but I don't understand why that should make a difference.

If it does, how do I convert the column to be numeric?

Comment: I suspect you have mixed dtype in your BRANDED column what does `df.info()` show? as an example I tested with all float including missing values and then a column with mixture of float and str and then I got the same result as you

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are quite right, `df.info()` shows `generic       7955 non-null float64` but `branded       5158 non-null object`. Looking at `branded` it seems to have some Python `None` objects in it. I guess I need to convert these to 0.0?

Comment: I would like the `branded` column to be of the same length as the `generic` column, filled with 0 values where necessary. I just tried `df.fillna(value=0.0)` but that doesn't seem to help. Same results from `info()` afterwards.

Comment: `None` will be converted to `NaN` I think, are you sure they are not str `'None'`?

Comment: I'm really not sure what they are. If I do `print df[:1]['branded']` I see `0    None Name: branded, dtype: object`: if I do `print type(df[:1]['branded'])` then I see `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. What are these and how can I convert them to zeros, or NaNs? I'd like to convert every such value in the dataframe to zero simultaneously.

Comment: If you're running pandas version `0.17.0` or higher try `pd.to_numeric(df['branded'])` this will convert the errant values to `NaN` or raise an error, otherwise try `df['b'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: You may well see the issue if you do `df['branded'].value_counts().index.tolist()` this will show if you have str or not

Comment: Thanks. I'm using pandas 0.16.2 (bundled with the Google Cloud Datalab). I tried `df['branded'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` but I still see the same results.

Comment: Trying `df['branded'].value_counts().index.tolist()` just shows me a list of numeric items from 1 upwards, both before and after the `convert_numeric` call.

Comment: What I don't understand is that if I do `len(df['branded']` I see 8173, but if I do `df['branded'].describe()` the first line of output is `count     5158`. Is it possible that the evaluation of `df['branded']` somehow excludes null/None values, or whatever weird datatype these None values actually are?

Comment: OK `df.replace('None', 0.0, inplace=True)` seems to solve the mixed types problem. Although it then replaces everything with `NaN`, not zero, which is NOT what I want!

Comment: So what does `len(df['branded'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True))` show? also I'm assuming you are assigning back the return from `convert_objects`

Comment: Are you able to post raw data and code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: `print len(df['branded_items'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True))` shows 8173, but then `print df['branded_items'].describe()['count']` shows 5158.0. The raw data comes from BigQuery so won't be easy to post here, but I'll try to post a simplification that demonstrates the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah - I see the problem now - `df.fillna(0.0)` does not replace in-place, I needed to do `df.replace('None', 0.0, inplace=True)` first, then `df = df.fillna(value=0.0)`. Odd that the first command replaces the `None` strings with `NaN` rather than 0, but that seems to be the case. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the column to be `numeric` or `float64` make use of `astype()`

```
df["branded"] = df["branded"].astype("float64")
```

Comment: This fails to answer the OP's question